# No matching signature for operator AND for argument types: BOOL, TIME. Supported signature: BOOL AND ([BOOL, ...])

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hello this is the query I am using  to get data

```
SELECT * 
FROM `nyc.a.ab` 
WHERE name = 'HB' 
AND TIME_ADD(CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL -5 minute)
LIMIT 5
```

I get this error

```
No matching signature for operator AND for argument types: BOOL, BOOL, TIME. Supported signature: BOOL AND ([BOOL, ...])
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix the issue 
What Iam trying to accomplish to to get the last 5 mins of data

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is the date field you want to filter in the table? Try : `date_field  >= DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL -5 MINUTE)`

Answer (score 2):

The error seems pretty clear.  You need a comparison:

```
WHERE name = 'HB' AND
      TIME_ADD(CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL -5 minute) > <SOME TIME VALUE GOES HERE>
```

Comment: this is where I am confused isnt current time my time value?

Comment: No, five minutes before the current time is.

Comment: what I am doing is to get the last 5 minutes worth of data is my logic correct?